# How can I make these mesh normals smooth?

Tags: uv, image, uv-image-editor

The UV image seems like a paper and not perfectly round
I duplicate the bottle's front and made it the label of the product.
But how can i make the unwrapping perfectly smooth?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't _think_ it's the unwrapping? Is it something like a bevel before a subdiv, making an uneven distribution of vertical edges along the curve?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response @RobinBetts , I'm really new in blender, so I might explain this wrong. please check the new image. there is bevel and subdiv. How can i solve this ? I couldnt figured it.

Edit:  Oh yes I see now my fault :(  like you said i did remove the subdiv and its perfect now...  thank you very much!

Comment: Something is 'breaking' the curvature on your cylinder. The bevel modifier was a good suspect, but you have the cut-off set to 30 so it shouldn't be causing that problem unless something funny is going on. If you upload your blend file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ we can take a closer look and figure out what is going on.

Comment: Thank you very much I have figured it out by removing subdiv.